# Unable to use Anypoint MQ in mule flow

Tags: java, mule-studio, mule-esb

I am learning mule ESB and using Anypoint Studio version 6.4.1. I was trying to create a flow containing composite Source. I wanted to add FTP, HTTP and Anypoint MQ connectors to composite source. Whenever i drag Anypoint MQ connector into composite source, it disappears. It doesn't get added. I can add other connectors fine. Not sure why I am not able to add Anypoint MQ to the composite source.

EDIT: Added a picture of what I am trying to do. Flow has a composite source scope and it will need to have HTTP, FTP and AnypointMQ connectors as described in this image

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Do clean and build your project and restart your Anypoint studio.

Because i have tried adding the AnypointMQ connector in my flow.Please find the attached screen shot.
[Added Anypoint MQ in composite source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Ybf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OV2N.png)

Comment: Added edits. I am able to add Anypoint MQ into the flow but not into Composite Source Scope.

Comment: @Sannu :It is not accepting from GUI but for work around you can add directly from xml configuration file. The same i have done and added attachment in the above comment.